# save entity in core data after editing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I have some ViewControllers. In the first LoginViewController, where I login, I create newEntity. By clicking on button "Login" I make fetch and assign for this newEntity fetch by predicate "login". AppDelegate.h have create things for Core Data. In LoginViewController I have next strings in .h:

```
@class AppDelegate;
...
@property (strong, nonatomic) AppDelegate *appMeDelegate;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *context;
...
```

In LoginViewController.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
...
@synthesize ... appMeDelegate, context;
...
//I have login button where i compare login and password in 
//UITextFields with that in Core Data and if it is 
//all right i load fetch for user with his login
-(IBAction)login:
{
appMeDelegate = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
context = appMeDelegate.managedObjectContext;
NSFetchRequest * fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
NSPredicate *predicateMe = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"login==%@",login.text];
fetchRequest.predicate = predicateMe;
... //then I create newEntity }
//next method for saving
-(void)saving
{
NSError *error = nil;
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}}
```

And then in other ViewController i use newEntity but can not save it

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSData *newdata = [NSData dataWithData:self.loginViewController.newEntity.photo];
photoArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:
[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:newdata]];}

-(IBAction)save
 {  [photoArray addObject:myImage];
NSData *newData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:photoArray];
[self.loginViewController.newEntity setValue:newData forKey:@"photo"];
[self.loginViewController saving];
```

But no results and it didn't save changing in entity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use something like this to save your managedDocument context

```
    [self.managedDocument saveToURL: self.managedDocument.fileURL forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForOverwriting completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
    if (completionHandler) completionHandler(success);
}];
```

**EDIT**
Sorry, just saw you are obviously not using an NSManagedDocument (which you should look into).

Dont do this:

```
[self.loginViewController saving];
```

Do it like you did before:

```
appMeDelegate = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = appMeDelegate.managedObjectContext;
[context save: &error];
```

Comment: yeah i don't use NSManagedDocument

Comment: I use debugger and  I see that my method -(void)saving is not called =( Why? It goes through this string [self.loginViewController saving] but don't go to method for saving. And where I need write this strings, that you write me (appMeDelegate = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = appMeDelegate.managedObjectContext;
[context save: &error];)?

Comment: Most likely because the .loginViewController reference wasnt properly set. You should get a reference to the context through the app delegate and use what I wrote in your "other ViewController" save method (as I said, instead of "[self.loginViewController saving];")

Comment: AppDelegate.h was import and now i write AppDelegate *appMeDelegate = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = appMeDelegate.managedObjectContext;
          NSError *error = nil;
        if(![context save: &error])
        
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);

With debugger i saw like it run string if(![context save:&error]) and didn't write any error in command line, but when i close app and run it again i see that nothing was saving =(

Comment: I see you also access the entity to change through accessing the reference to your loginViewController. I think thats the problem, because that obviously hasent been set correctly. In your other ViewController save method, check self.loginViewController for nil. I think it is nil or its property .newEntity is nil

Comment: oh yeah you right, I check if(self.loginPassViewController==nil)
    NSLog(@"that's nil"); and it is nil =( So I need to create entity in "other ViewController" with fetch by that login with which I entered?

Comment: Yes, if I understand correctly. For further concrete questions open a new topic since this discussion is going on too long